Spoiler blocks do not function in inbox notification
It is very easy to get spoiled on an answer via the inbox. Example (don't click if you don't want to be spoiled on this question)

 

As you can see in the spoilered image, all the words after "clues" are supposed to be in a spoiler block, but they showed in the inbox notification regardless.
Is it possible to have spoilers work in inboxes?
Or, as a workaround, perhaps users should be prompted when they put spoilers too early (e.g. in the first 100 characters) of a question or answer?

I think working spoilers in the inbox is a reasonable request. I don't think encouraging users not to use them in the first x number of characters is viable or good for answer quality, as it will lead to pointless waffle at the top of an answer just to fill space.

Main-meta duplicate - there's nothing we can do here to change how cross-site stuff (e.g the inbox) works. It has to go through the central cross-site meta.
